# I want to use sed to replace every occurrence of /dir with $dir (replace / with $) in every script in a directory

Tags: sed

use sed to replace every occurrence of /dir  with $dir (replace / with $) in every script in a directory.

sed "s#/dir#$dir#g"

The $ keeps being interpreted as a function or variable call.
Is there a way around this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read your shell's friendly manual:

```
man sh
```

In the shell, "double quotes" around text allow variable interpretation inside, while 'single quotes' do not, a convention adopted by later languages such as Perl and PHP (but not e.g. JavaScript).

```
sed 's#/dir#$dir#g' *
```

To perform the replacement within the scripts do something like

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type f | while read f; do  mv $f $f.old && sed 's#/dir#$dir#' $f.old > $f; done
```

or just

```
perl -pi.old -e 's#/dir#\$dir#' *  # Perl also interpolates variables in s commands
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply escape it with a backslash:

```
sed "s#/dir#\$dir#g"
```

Answer (score 0):

shell approach

```
for file in file*
do
  if [ -f "$file ];then
      while read -r line
        case "$line" in 
          */dir* ) line=${line///dir/\$dir}
        esac
        echo $line > temp    
      done < "file"
      mv temp $file
  fi
done
```